# What is python's not? A special function type?

Tags: python, r, infix-operator

In R, ! is really an infix operator `!`, so statements like

```
Map(`!`,c(T,F,F))
```

are totally valid. Is there a way to access the first order object underlying not in Python? I have been googling with no success.

Comment: The word "so" in your question doesn't really make sense.  The fact that something is an infix operator does not imply that you will be able to use it like a function.  Rather, what lets you do that in R is the fact that R makes its operators available as builtin functions with similar names (i.e., names that include symbols).  `not` is an operator in Python as well, it's just that Python doesn't also let you use operators as functions (you have to use the function versions, as described in Martijn's answer).

Comment: OK. That explains it. I was thinking the wrong way. \`!\` isn't the operation called, \`!\` is a function invoking !

Comment: Snot an infix operator in R. It's a prefix operator just like binary "-" and possibly `~`. The explanation may apply to Python but not to R. You can use: `"!"(FALSE)`. You just need to quote the operator because there are parsing rules about function names.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Python has the [`operator` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html), which includes a [`operator.not_()` function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.not_):

```
import operator

map(operator.not_, (True, False, False))
```

`not` itself is one of the [boolean operators](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#boolean-operations).

Comment: so sans the operator module, what is it? I'm just trying to understand how Python thinks. You can obviously do things like def myNot(x): return(not(x)), but I want to get a sense of what not is.

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion: It is an operator, as noted [here](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/expressions.html#not).

Comment: @ProbablyAStupidQuestion: `not` is a unary operator.